# Filtering an aggregated calculated table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, data-modeling, calculated-columns

I created an aggregated table using the following DAX expression:

```
Machine Data = 
SUMMARIZE (
    'Table',
    'Table'[Machine ID],
    "Total Production", [Total Production (m3)],
    "Total Trips", [Total Trips],
    "Total Ignition On Hrs", [Ignition On Hours],
    "Total Utilization Hrs", [Utilization Hours],
)

then I am further categorizing each [Machine ID] in 'Machine Data' into Categories based on 'Total Production' value using:

[Category Allocation DAX][1]
```

I have already created a display table based on measures only which can be filtered by date slicer.

```
[visual table from measures from 'Data' (responsive to date slicer)][2]
```

However, I think that calculated table is necessary as I want to further aggregate the 'Machine Data' table based on the Categories. Calculated table 'Machine Data' is not responding to the Date slicers filters.

'Table' has a [Date] for every row which is related to 'Date Table'[Date]. Currently, the 'Machine Data' is not related to any field in 'Date Table' and 'Table' (from which it is aggregated) in modelling section. Since the 'Machine Data' does not has date column hence I understand why the slicer is not working however, since it is aggregated from 'Table' which is related to a 'Date Table' hence I was hoping that anyone could help me out in utilizing that.

In short, my 'Table' granularity is per machine per day. 'Machine Data' is aggregated data per machine. Then I want to another calculated table aggregating 'Machine Data' by Categories which I can visualize.

My final calculated table should look like this based on that, I can create a visualization. However, this table should be response to date slicers.

[Final aggregated Calculated Table (should be responsive date slicers)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhOJH.png)

Let me know if you guys need more details. I have tried numerous queries to solve this issue but can't seem to find a solution.